# Does "Request Trial Capacity" for Platform Cache work in scratch orgs?

Tags: scratch-org, platform-cache

I clicked the "Request Trial Capacity" button 20 minutes ago in a scratch org and [Get Started with Platform Cache](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/platform_cache/platform_cache_get_started) says:

> Click Request Trial Capacity and wait for the email notifying you that
>   your Platform Cache trial is active. Salesforce approves trial
>   requests immediately, but it can take a few minutes for you to receive
>   the email.

but no email and still a "Trial Request Pending" message in the refreshed page.

Is more patience needed, or are scratch orgs not supported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Platform Cache in scratch orgs is coming in Summer 19 but not here yet.

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer19/release-notes/rn_apex_platformcache_for_scratchorg.htm

Comment: Thanks Charles. I can create a zero size partition that does mean the Cache.CacheBuilder implementation runs - always a miss - so that is something.